# Разработка приложения на Qt под ios

Tags: qt, ios, эмулятор

Каким эмулятором лучше воспользоваться для разработки и отладки приложения под ios? Само приложение разрабатываю на Qt.

Answer (score 1):

Эмуляторов iOS не существует – есть только официальный *симулятор* от Apple, устанавливающийся вместе с Xcode, так что выбора, где отлаживать, особо и нет, если нет реального iOS-устройства.